# Ajax/Javascript Delete Confirm Text Without Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have searched everywhere but cannot seem to find any examples anywhere of what I am trying to achieve.

I have a Delete button, and when you press the button I would like the text to appear on the screen without the page refreshing asking the user with Yes/No hyperlinks (not buttons) if they want to delete their message. I strictly do not want to use a modal or dialog, I just want text on screen.

I have tried the following script on the ajax page but doesnt do exactly what I want:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>

<button type='submit' name='btn-delete' id='btn-delete' onclick='loadDoc()'>Delete</button>
```

As my button is set to submit, I know its posting to the next page before asking the user for delete confirmation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try removing the `type='submit'` and submit at the end of your javascript function by targeting the `<form>` DOM element and calling `.submit()` on it.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to use ajax, enough to do any div hidden with buttons, and when the button 'btn-delete' clicked, show the hidden div.

Comment: You put literally no effort into formatting that code.

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to support IE6 in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vho2er4/1/)

You essentially need to first wrap your markup in a container `<div>` to append your confirmation `<a>` tags when they are created.

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>
</div>
```

Then create the confirmation `<a>` tags and append them to the container `<div>`.

```
var node = document.createElement("a");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Yes");
node.appendChild(textnode);
node.id = 'confirm-delete';
node.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(node);
```

Then fire the request when the user clicks the newly created `<a>` tag.

```
document.getElementById('confirm-delete').onclick = function confirmation() {
  // ...
}
```